# Error when creating database name using full of number in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Create a database name using string, database will create successfully.

Example :

```
if db_id('Database1') is null create database Database1
```

> Command(s) completed successfully.

But create database name using full of number, it having a problem

Example :

```
if db_id('1234567890') is null create database 1234567890
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '1234567890'.

Is anything wrong in my query?

Comment: No this is also getting same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
IF DB_ID('1234567890') IS NULL 
    CREATE DATABASE [1234567890]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use double quote

```
IF DB_ID('1234567890') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE "1234567890"
```